# give a function as parameter

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a function as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java)

How can i give a function as parameter?

for example:

```
for(Confetti c : confetti) {
   b.draw(someFunction(){strokeWeight(random(10));
}
```

where in the confetti class there would be something like

```
draw(void myFunc){
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myFunc(); // run it
    ellipse(50, 50, 5, 5);
   }
}
```

Comment: there are a lot of errors in the code you've given us to start.

Comment: Maybe you'll have a look at Reflections:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/methods.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Java does not treat functions as first class objects. What you can do is define an interface with a method that contains the function you want called.

```
interface Confetti {
   public void draw();
}

class DrawRandomStroke implements Confetti {
 public void draw() {
      strokeWeight(random(10));
}
```

And then pass your DrawRandomStroke objects to your method. If you want to use a language that supports what you're trying to do and still be in the java world, look at groovy or scala.