# How to pass a member function as a parameter in java?

Tags: java

My `collect()` function calls `Foo.f()`. I would like to make `Foo.f()` itself a parameter of my function. Is this possible in Java?

- How can I pass either `Foo.f()` or `Foo.g()` (or any other function of `Foo` that returns a `String`) to my function?
- Is there an already existing function which walks a collection and collects the result of calling a method of every collection item?

.

```
class Foo {
    public String f() { return "f"; }
    public String g() { return "g"; }
    // ...
}

public List<String> collect(List<Foo> foos)
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (final Foo foo: foos) {
        result.add(foo.f());  // I want Foo.f to be a parameter
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Update**

I would like to point out the fact that I am not merely calling the same function but rather the member function `f` for all items of the `List<Foo>` collection.

Comment: You can always use the reflection API and pass a Method object.

Comment: Or you could create an interface...

Comment: Check out the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). Function pointers don't exist in java, except with reflection

Comment: For your first question check below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java

Comment: (a) interface, (b) reflection, (c) - switch to C# :) Come to the dark side, we have cookies :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 8, you can do

```
collect(foos, Foo::f);

public List<String> collect(List<Foo> foos, Function<Foo,String> func)
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (final Foo foo: foos) {
        result.add(func.apply(foo));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Or with steam API

```
Stream<Foo> foos = ...;
Stream<String> strs = foos.map(Foo::f);
```

Comment: Java 8 is not exactly stable yet. In earlier versions of Java, closures and function pointers are not supported.

Comment: @RudolphEst But if you were asking this question, you probably aren't going to be producing much software for a while. Might as well use Java SE 8 now. / Java SE 8 does not have function pointers, and "lambdas" aren't really any more of a closure than anonymous inner classes (the point being that the syntax is less verbose).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline It depends. If the OP is a student at university, he might be constrained to use Java 7 in his projects.

Answer (score 5):

You can use interfaces

```
  interface Foo
  {
      String fn();
  }
```

and pass the interface to the method

```
 void anyMethod(Foo f)
 {
   f.fn();
 }
```

you dont need to create a concrete `Foo`, just create `Foo` anonymously

```
  new Foo() {

  @Override
  public String fn()
  {
   return "something";
  }
};
```

In Java 8 you don't need to anonymously implement the interface. You could use a lambda expression instead.

```
  anyMethod(()-> "something");
```

Comment: I don't see, how this solution works with `collect()` since I am not calling simply the same function but rather the same function for *different* items of the collection.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann you can simply call any method inside fn()

Answer (score 0):

In Java you are not supposed to pass method as a parameter, but you can pass an object as parameter.

It is called [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), you would need to use interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface like:

```
interface IFoo {
    String getString();
}
```

Then implement it in the custom ways:

```
class F implements IFoo {
    public String getString() {
        return "f";
    }
}

class G implements IFoo {
    public String getString() {
        return "g";
    }
}
```

And have your function take a list of anything that implements `IFoo`:

```
public List<String> collect(List<? extends IFoo> foos)
{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (final IFoo foo: foos) {
        result.add(foo.getString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
for (String a : collect(Arrays.asList(new F(), new G()))) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
    //Prints f and g
```