# Passing a function to another function as a parameter in Java

Tags: java

I am very new to Java and trying to figure this problem out. Given the year, the month and day, I have to validate it first and do addition and subtraction to the date.

```
public class Date {



// fields

private int month;

private int day;

private int year;



// constructor

public Date(int month, int day, int year){

    this.month = month;

    this.day = day;

    this.year = year;

}


public void setMonth(int month){

    this.month = month;

}



public void setDay(int day){

    this.day = day;

}



public void setYear(int year){

    this.year = year;

}



public int getMonth(){

    return month;

}



public int getDay(){

    return day;

}



public int getYear(){

    return year;

}



public String displayDate(){

    return month + "/" + day + "/" + "/" + year;

}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java

Comment: Where in your code are you calling the function `add` ?

Comment: There seems a lots of problem in your code .. please check the syntax

Comment: Instead of `if (x) return true; else return false;`, just do `return x`. It'll simplify things quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer I can give based on the code is what your error message says.
In your function

```
public int add( int n){...}
```

you are trying to use the variable `m` which does not exist.
You can pass this variable as another parameter where you call the add function.

```
public int add( int n, int m){...}
...
myDateObject.add(3,6);
```

The other possibility is to save the validated month's value into the `private int month` field first. Then use it in the add function instead of the nonexistent `m` variable.

Edit:

There are a lot of problem with this code. For example in order to run this program you would need a main method where your program can start executing. The constructor of your class tries to give value to fields that does not exsist(`this.d = d;` instead of `this.day = d;`). If this truly is the whole code I'd suggest to try to read / write and understand a java Hello World example first. :)

Comment: I am very new to java. I included the whole program.

Comment: I modified the class Date. Can you help with how do I put this main? If I wanted to instantiate this class (Date), how would I do that? I am really stuggling with this.

Comment: Create another file named Program.java with this code:

class Program {
   
   public static void main(string [] args) {

     Date date = new Date(5,25,2012);
     date.setYear(2013);
     System.out.println(date.displayDate());

   }
}