# what's difference between a callback and observer pattern in java

Tags: java, callback, observer-pattern

I was going through the following link in stack over flow

**[How do I perform a JAVA callback between classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279302/how-do-i-perform-a-java-callback-between-classes)**

In the particular question **answer 18** refers to *callbacks* and **answer 9** refers to the *observer pattern*.

I am unable to distinguish the difference between both.

Can anyone please explain where these two approaches differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A callback is basically a piece of code that your provide for a class and gets called by it at a certain point. Ex:

```
serverConnectionHandler = new ServerConnections(new ITypedCallback<Socket>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Socket socket) {
            // do something with your socket here
        }
});
```

The observer's pattern is a design pattern that is based on callbacks. You can find more details about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Question should instead be framed as how observer pattern helps in achieving callback functionality.

I wanted to give clear example which explains callbacks in a way how listeners (observers) works - following approach is greatly adopted by android library.

```
class RemoteClass {

    private OnChangeListener mOnChangeListener;

    void makeSomeChanges() {
        /*
        .. do something here and call callback
        */
        mOnChangeListener.onChanged(this, 1);
    }

    public void setOnChangeListener(OnChangeListener listener) {
        mOnChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnChangeListener {
        public void onChanged(RemoteClass remoteClass, int test);
    }
}
```

There is a class built my someone, which goes by name `RemoteClass` and tells your class to reference the callback by passing implementation of `OnChangeListener`  interface to `setOnChangeListener` method.

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        RemoteClass obj = new RemoteClass();
        obj.setOnChangeListener(demoChanged);
        obj.makeSomeChanges();
    }

    private static RemoteClass.OnChangeListener demoChanged = new RemoteClass.OnChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(RemoteClass remoteClass, int incoming) {
            switch (incoming) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("I will take appropriate action!");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Now your class has finished doing its task and `RemoteClass` does its work and upon calling `makeSomeChanges` whenever necessary results in `onChanged` method execution using `mOnChangeListener` reference.