# Callback in Java vs Scripting Languages

Tags: javascript, java, callback, scripting-language

I was looking at [How do I perform a JAVA callback between classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279302/how-do-i-perform-a-java-callback-between-classes). And the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279302/how-do-i-perform-a-java-callback-between-classes#answer-18279545), answered my query.

```
interface CallBack {
    void methodToCallBack();
}

class CallBackImpl implements CallBack {
    public void methodToCallBack() {
        System.out.println("I've been called back");
    }
}

class Caller {

    public void register(CallBack callback) {
        callback.methodToCallBack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caller caller = new Caller();
        CallBack callBack = new CallBackImpl();
        caller.register(callBack);
    }
}
```

However, it challenges my concept of `callback` from scripting languages like JavaScript. Where implementation of `callback` functions are passed from the caller. for example,

```
function IWillCallTheCallBack(callback) {
      callback();
}
```

Can anyone explain the difference between callback in Java vs other programming language.

Comment: Callbacks aren't really used in Java. In Java we achieve polymorphism through inheritance and interfaces instead. We can pass around instances of classes instead of functions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way might be to use a lambda of a `Runnable`. The advantage of this is that it can be called back asynchronously, on another Thread, if you want.

```
public class CallbackTest {

    public static void run(Runnable callback) {
        callback.run();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(()-> System.out.println("I've been called"));
    }
}
```