# How to implement callbacks properly

Tags: java, android, oop, mqtt, implements

I have two objects that needs callback implementation, what if both objects need different implementation? if i implement it at class level by implement keyword, interface methods only appear once in that activity, also If I'm calling both callback on the same object it only execute first callback, here is my code: same object but different implementation of interface method, in this case only the first callback executed that called first

```
client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                @Override
                public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

                }

                @Override
                public void messageArrived(String topic, 
                    MqttMessage message) throws Exception {

                }

                @Override
                public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {


                    try {
                        MqttMessage message = token.getMessage();

                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            });
```

same object different implementation:

```
client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void messageArrived(String topic, 
MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                        tv.append(message.toString());
                        Log.i("MainActivity", " Mesages" + message);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Maybe use an interface? or Use overloading? Maybe this link helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279302/how-do-i-perform-a-java-callback-between-classes

Comment: what exactly is not working with your callback???