# Asynchronous executing piece of code (start thread at place)

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, spring-boot

My stack is `spring-boot` and `myBatis`. 
I am going to execute some piece of code asynchronously, more exactly:

```
@RestController
class Controller 
{
   @PutMapping("/endpoint")
   Response foo () 
   {
      doSomeStuffAsynchronously(); //execute in new thread
      return new Response(); // immediately 
   }
}
```

How should I do it ?

**Edit**
I don't need a callback, however it will be nice to see how to do it.

> Learn to use interfaces

I know what is interface, however I can't see how it helps. Can you help me, please ?

Comment: Like this? What is the problem? You need callbacks? Learn to use interfaces.

Comment: @MattClark I edited and referenced to your comment.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18279548/1790644)

Comment: I think that it is overkill here in my case, don't you ?

Comment: You still have not stated what the problem is, or what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you need to execute something asynchronously with a call back this is what it takes. If you do not need a callback and can return immediately do what you already posted

Comment: I only shown what I want to. However, I don't know how to reach this effect. (Keep in mind that I am using spring boot)