# Can't return location from one activity to another

Tags: android, mysql, google-maps

I am trying to fetch latitude and longitude from mysql database using AsyncTask and show it on Map.I have created a class which gets the location from database
here is the method which returns the location from database

```
 public Location addEmployee() {


    class AddEmployee extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        //ProgressDialog loading;

       /* @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Retreiving...", "Wait...", false, false);
        }*/

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String success) {
           // super.onPostExecute(success);
            //loading.dismiss();

            try {
                parseJSON(success);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("busid", busid);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String res = rh.sendPostRequest("https://tkajbaje.000webhostapp.com/php/busid.php", params);
            return res;
        }
        public void parseJSON(final String success) throws JSONException {
             JSONObject jsonObject;

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(success);
            if (jsonObject.has("Latitude")) {
                location.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("Latitude")));

            }
            if (jsonObject.has("Longitude")) {
                location.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("Longitude")));



            }

        }
    }
    AddEmployee ae = new AddEmployee();
    ae.execute();
    return(location);

}
```

I have another activity which gets the location from the above function and shows it on map.here is the code

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String busid=String.valueOf(1);
    Location location;
   MainActivity activity=new MainActivity(busid);
    location=activity.addEmployee();


   double Latitude=location.getLatitude();
    Toast.makeText(MapsMarkerActivity.this,String.valueOf(Latitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    double Longitude=location.getLongitude();

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Bus location"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

But the latitude and longitude always happen to be 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Cuz, it starts the AsyncTask and return the location object(whatever the state of that object is). it will not wait for AsyncTask to complete the execution.

**Solution:-**
You can create an interface in that class and execute in `onPostExecute()` implement the Interface in activity or use it Anonymously with Class object. Now, whenever it callbacks you can do rest of the work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where the `location` is defined, however it looks like you are mixing asynchronous and synchronous code.

```
AddEmployee ae = new AddEmployee();
ae.execute();
return(location);
```

In this part, you invoke an asynchronous task which will assign `location` a new value if the task is successful, however the keyword here is asynchronous, here `location` will return before Async Task is completed. You can create a Listener and call it in `onPostExecute`.

```
MainActivity activity=new MainActivity(busid);
location=activity.addEmployee();
```

Here, I strongly recommend making a new class and putting addEmployee there (and other logic that is not specific to the Activity). Creating a new activity with new keyword is not a good approach.

Comment: How do i create a listner and call it in onPostExecute.?

Comment: SRB bans described a rough implementation, you can also search Java callback for more examples. One example would be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18279545/1364138