# How to make a method a parameter for a constructor

Tags: java

While making a small game in Java, I stumbled upon the keyListener class, which asks for three methods when instanced (keyTyped, keyPressed, and keyReleased), as below:

```
JFrame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evnt) {
    //blah
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evnt) {
    //blah
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evnt) {
    //blah
    }
});
```

How can I get a class I am making on my own accept methods as a parameter as above?

Comment: Take a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new KeyListener() { ... }` actually creates an anonymous inner class that implements `KeyListener`. As such it can access any visible field of the class that created it as well as any local final variable inside the method that called the constructor.

Example:

```
class Outer {
  int x;

  void initUI( final int z) {
    final int y = 0;        
    int nope = 1; //you can't access this since it is neither final nor a field like x

    JFrame.addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {
      public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evnt) {
        System.out.println( x + y + z ); //you can access all of them
      }
    });
  }
}
```

If you want to provide a constructor for your key listener you'll need to explicitly define a class, as [anonymous classes can't have custom constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5.1). That means you'd have to do something like this (attention: pseudo code):

```
class Outer {
  void initUI() {
    JFrame.addKeyListener( new InnerKeyListener( myParam ) );
  }

  class InnerKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    InnerKeyListener( Param p ) {
    }

    ...
  }
}
```

Of course you can put the inner class into a separe file as well or make it a static inner class.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, those methods aren't parameters here.  The only parameter is the one anonymous instance of a KeyListener.

KeyListener is an `interface` that requires those 3 methods to be implemented.

If you want to define your own interface, it looks similar to a class:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public void foo();
    public int bar(int x);
}
```

Then you can use it anonymously (like in your example), or by implementing it in a class:

```
public class MyClass implements SomeInterface {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not accepting methods as a parameter.  You're declaring an anonymous class and passing that as a parameter into the addKeyListener method.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is weird to answer my own question, but...

I figured it out. You have to make your class abstract, and you can declare abstract methods to make methods "parameters" to have it behave like a KeyListener declaration. Abstract methods are declared like this:

```
    abstract ReturnType name(Parameter p);
```

and behave exactly like methods when called. For a full example:

```
    //The abstract keyword enables abstract methods to work with this class.
    abstract class Foo {
        //Just a random variable and a constructor to initialize it
        int blah;
        public Foo(int blah) {
            this.blah = blah;
        }
        //An abstract method 
        abstract void doStuff();
        //Example with a parameter
        abstract void whatDoIDoWith(int thisNumber);
        //A normal method that will call these methods.
        public void doThings() {
            //Call our abstract method.
            doStuff();
            //Call whatDoIDoWith() and give it the parameter 5, because, well... 5!
            whatDoIDoWith(5);
        }
    }
```

When you try to instance an abstract class like a normal class, Java will freak out.

```
    Foo f = new Foo(4);
```

What you will have to do is something like this:

```
    Foo f = new Foo(4) {
        @Override
        void doStuff() {
            System.out.println("Hi guys! I am an abstract method!");
        }
        @Override
        void whatDoIDoWith(int thisNumber) {
            blah += thisNumber;
            System.out.println(blah);
        }
     }; //Always remember this semicolon!
```

Note that you need to include all of the abstract methods here, not just some of them. Now, let's try this:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Instance foo.
            Foo f = new Foo(4) {
                @Override
                void doStuff() {
                    System.out.println("Hi guys! I am an abstract method!");
                }
                @Override
                void whatDoIDoWith(int thisNumber) {
                    blah += thisNumber;
                    System.out.println(blah);
                }
            };
            //Call our method where we called our two abstract methods.
            foo.doThings();
        }
    }
```

This prints the following to the console:

```
    Hi guys! I am an abstract method!
    9
```