# A good way to refactor code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have several DTO objects.

```
public class MovieRequest {}
public class OtherTitle extends MovieRequest {}
public class ReleaseDate extends MovieRequest {}
```

These objects are uploaded using a generic contribution(DTO object)
`public class ContributionNew<T extends MovieRequest> {}` to the methods

```
void createOtherTitleContribution(
        final ContributionNew<OtherTitle> contribution,
        ...
);
void updateOtherTitleContribution(
        final ContributionUpdate<OtherTitle> contribution,
        ...
);
 void createReleaseDateContribution(
        final ContributionNew<ReleaseDate> contribution,
        ...
);
void updateReleaseDateContribution(
        final ContributionUpdate<ReleaseDate> contribution,
        ...
);
```

Information for films is more and these methods will be duplicated about 30 times f. e. `createBoxOfficeContribution` e.t.c
For example, the method of updating contributions looks like this

```
@Override
public void updateOtherTitleContribution(
        ContributionUpdate<OtherTitle> contribution,
        Long contributionId,
        Long userId
) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    log.info("Called with contribution {}, contributionId {}, userId {}",
            contribution, contributionId, userId);

    final UserEntity user = this.findUser(userId);
    final ContributionEntity contributionEntity = this.findContribution(contributionId, EditStatus.WAITING, user, MovieField.OTHER_TITLE);

    this.validIds(contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd(), contribution.getElementsToAdd().keySet());
    this.validIds(contributionEntity.getIdsToUpdate().keySet(), contribution.getElementsToUpdate().keySet());
    this.validIds(contributionEntity.getIdsToDelete(), contribution.getIdsToDelete());

    this.cleanUpIdsToAdd(contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd(), contribution.getElementsToAdd().keySet(), contributionEntity.getMovie().getOtherTitles());
    this.cleanUpIdsToUpdate(contributionEntity.getIdsToUpdate(), contribution.getElementsToUpdate().keySet());
    this.cleanUpIdsToDelete(contributionEntity.getIdsToDelete(), contribution.getIdsToDelete());

    contribution.getElementsToAdd().forEach((key, value) -> {
        this.moviePersistenceService.updateOtherTitle(value, key, contributionEntity.getMovie());
    });
    contribution.getElementsToUpdate().forEach((key, value) -> {
        this.moviePersistenceService.updateOtherTitle(value, key, contributionEntity.getMovie());
    });
    contribution.getNewElementsToAdd()
            .forEach(otherTitle -> {
                final Long id = this.moviePersistenceService.createOtherTitle(otherTitle, contributionEntity.getMovie(), user);
                contributionEntity.getIdsToAdd().add(id);
            });

    contributionEntity.setSources(contribution.getSources());
    Optional.ofNullable(contribution.getComment()).ifPresent(contributionEntity::setUserComment);
}
```

As you can see, the only difference in these methods is to call the method

```
this.moviePersistenceService.updateOtherTitle(...)
```

And the method updateReleaseDateContribution calls

```
this.moviePersistenceService.updateReleaseDate(...)
```

As you can see the difference is only a few lines, and the old way the current code will have several thousand lines. Do you have any idea for a universal generic method? How to do it better?

Comment: Are you using repository to update the entity?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

- you can create a method `moviePersistenceService.update(MovieRequest req)` that will check the type of `req` before doing the persistence part.
- You can also pass a Function (the one that will do the persistence part) as parameter to  `updateOtherTitleContribution`  (check [How to pass a function as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java))

Comment: 1. You mean something that I check e.g if( req instanceof OtherTitle) ?

Comment: yes, in your persistence classe because i guess you are storing the data in differente tables (or collections) or something.

Comment: A little strange look will be over 15 conditions. In Java 8, this is unlikely.

Comment: Oh. Ok i thought it was only a few number of entities. So the best solution that i can think of is to create a persistence function for each of your entities and pass that function to updateOtherTitleContribution as suggested in my second point. Maybe someone else can provide with another solution.