# Is it possible to store a condition?

Tags: java

Beginner here, is there a way to pass a condition into a method? For example passing `(n > 1 && n < 10)` and then the method can replace `n` with some variable.

```
//request an int from the user
public static int requestInt(String request, /*SOME CONDITION*/)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(request);
    int response;
    while (true){
        while (!input.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("Invalid response");
            input.next();
        }
        response = input.nextInt();
        if(/*RESPONSE DOESN'T FIT THE CONDITION*/){
            System.out.println("Invalid response");
        }else{
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're looking to [pass in a function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). More specifically, a function that returns a boolean, or a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). See [How to pass a function as a parameter in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685563) and [Java Pass Method as Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2186931).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [functional interface](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-functional-programming/functional-interfaces.html) to represent the concept of a function from int → boolean. There are several in the [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package that fit the bill:

- [`Function<Integer, Boolean>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html): Represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.
- [`IntFunction<Boolean>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntFunction.html): Represents a function that accepts an int-valued argument and produces a result.
- [`Predicate<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html): Represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) of one argument.
- [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html): Represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) of one int-valued argument.

I've listed them in order from most generic to most specialized. Let's use the last one, `IntPredicate`, since it represents exactly what you want, a test using an integer:

```
public static int requestInt(String request, IntPredicate predicate) {
    // ...

    if (predicate.test(response)) {
        return response;
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Invalid response");
    }
}
```

Calling would look like this, using [lambda syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html):

```
requestInt(request, n -> (n > 1 && n < 10));
```

Comment: Is something like this but with a String possible too?

Comment: Sure. Use `Predicate<String>` or `Function<Integer, String>`.

Answer (score -2):

Okay so it's not exactly that easy, but it's still not that difficult.

```
private int someMethod(bool condition) {
  if (condition) {
    // Do your code
  } else {
    return -1; // -1 because that's typically used to denote invalid, but you can use null or anything else really.
  }
}
```