# Java - Pass a method call into a method

Tags: java

I have a a few lines of code which repeat itself in many methods:

```
public String removeItemsX() {
    MyReq myReq = new MyReq();
    myReq.setName(<String>);
        
    StandardResponse standardResponse = null;
    try {
        standardResponse = A.removeItemX(myReq); // This method call is different, the rest is the same
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
    
    return standardResponse;
}
```

Now I have many methods

```
removeItemX();
removeItemY();
removeItemZ();
...
```

which have almost the same code above, just the method calls are different:

```
A.removeItemX(myReq);
A.removeItemY(myReq);
A.removeItemZ(myReq);
    ...
```

Is it possible to define just one method, an pass into somehow only the different method calls?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685563/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java

Comment: This question is confusing. Perhaps you could rewrite to use a contrived but specific realistic-seeming example.

Comment: Can you not change method to `removeItem(int itemCode)`?

Comment: Have a look at function interfaces and lambdas which have been introduced in Java 8. However, even with Java 7 and earlier this would be possible just with a little more code (this basically is the strategy pattern).

Comment: Use the following method `String removeItems(Consumer<MyReq> callback) { ... }` and call it like so: `removeItems(A::removeItemX)`.

Comment: I cannot change anything about the method calls, because it is an API I use, which is coded that way. And I have to use it, that's why I asked the question, to not duplicate code many times.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: What to do with 'callback" inside the method body? If have to do callback.accept(...); it return void, but I need the StandardResponse from the method passed in.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. The use a `Function<MyReq, StandardResponse>` instead.