# how can I store an arraylist of void methods

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, void

Is it possible to store void type methods in an arrayList or can you only store methods that have a return value? I want to call any one of up to 15 methods and rather than write:

```
if(var == 1){
    method1()
}else if(var ==2){
    method2();
}
```

etc...

by the time you surround with try/catch and a few more lines of code (that repeat for each one) it would be much neater if you could do:

```
arrayList.get(var); //or something similar
```

However my methods just "do stuff" as opposed to return a value so if the methods themselves cannot be stored in an array is there somewhere else they can be stored together and extracted with a for loop or by just using the "var" integer?

Comment: What language are you asking this question about?

Comment: Sorry Bob talking about Java

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073358/function-pointers-in-java) what you need?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot store method references in Java.

However, you can create an object of a class that has a defined interface that allows you to invoke the method readily.

```
public interface VoidMethod {
  public void callMethod();
}

// ...

public class Method1 implements VoidMethod {
  public void callMethod() {
    // your stuff here
  }
}

// ...

public class MethodN implements VoidMethod {
  public void callMethod() {
    // your stuff here
  }
}
```

Then you can populate an object array with instances of VoidMethod.

Comment: Of course you can store method references, by getting a Method object reference.  The more tricky part is getting the Method object reference you want, usually by reflection.  Of course what you suggested is otherwise a reasonable suggestion, just factually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is given precisely by

```
java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.reflect.Method>
```

but it seems to me you should be using a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who comes to look at this post 6 years later like I was, I suggest you have your `ArrayList` return a String of `""`. If the value is not used, it wont matter whether it's there or not, but you'll need it to make the compiler happy.