# How to send function to call in other class in Java?

Tags: java

What I would like to do is send a function as parameter to other class' function. 
For example, I have UI.java class for UI and Timer.java class for the logic. So I would like to pass function of logic class to UI so that once a button is clicked, it will call function from Timer.java.

How can I do that? Is it recommended? standard for application development?

Comment: Did you try Command pattern? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: Any guide for that? How about Callable <T>?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you elaborate? There are multiple patterns and `Callable<T>` might be one of it. `Function<T, R>` might be an alternative and there are a lot of others - it all depends on what you're actually trying to do and what your code looks like.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073358/function-pointers-in-java)

Comment: I tried Callable <T> but there is an error while I am trying it. Do I need to put my sample code in my question?

Comment: @Abhi Yellow quote blocks are for quotations, not for emphasis. Use bold text or italics for emphasis. But only edit a post if you can objectively improve it. Don't just do it because you feel like it. Sure, no worries.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186931/java-pass-method-as-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) such as [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

```
class Bar
{
    public void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
}

class Foo
{
    private Runnable runnable;

    Foo(Runnable runnable)
    {
        this.runnable = runnable;
    }

    public void onCompletion()
    {
        this.runnable.run();
    }
}

Bar bar = new Bar();
Foo foo = new Foo(bar::doSomething);
foo.onCompletion();
```

The exact functional interface you'll want will depend on your use case. Have a look in [the package `java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) to find the one you need.

Comment: I'd rather use `Function` than `Runnable`, better typing.

Comment: @lexicore they're different functional interfaces. You can't simply substitute one for another. I chose Runnable here because it's the simplest.