# HashMap used to Call Methods - Minimizing If Else Statements

Tags: java, hashmap, if-statement

I'm not sure how to get round it.

Need help with details please

Answer (score 2):

You first create a `Map<String, Shape>`, containing all the possible commands as keys, and the corresponding shape as value:

```
Map<String, Shape> shapesByCommand = new HashMap<String, Shape>();
shapesByCommand.put("circle", new Circle());
shapesByCommand.put("sun", new Sun());
...
```

Then, when you receive the command, you get the corresponding shape and make it visible:

```
Shape shape = shapesByCommand.get(commands[0]);
if (shape != null && "visible".equals(commands[1])) {
    makeVisible(shape);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think JB Nizet' answer will probably help you, especially for the first part of your problem. However, if you are after a general solution for the second part of your question, namely how to call a function based on a string that you want to look up in a `HashMap`, what you probably want to do is store [function objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_Java) in that `HashMap`, and then call that function object after the lookup (you may also find [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599698/function-object-in-java) helpful).

Here's an example (using Strings rather than Shapes):

```
public interface Action {
    abstract void run(String s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<String, Action>();
    actions.put("visible", new Action() {
        public void run(String s) {
            System.out.println("Running 'visible' on: " + s);
        }
    });
    String input[];
    input = new String[2];
    input[0] = "sun";
    input[1] = "visible";
    actions.get(input[1]).run(input[0]);
}
```

Output:
`Running 'visible' on: sun`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a `HashMap` here, I would use an `EnumMap`

Then, in the code of your `enum`, you could put all the implementations as methods of the various `enum` subclasses.

```
public enum Actions {
  visible, move, resize;

  public doAction(Shape s) {
    switch(this) {
      case visible:
        // handle command
        break;
      case move:
        // etc.
  }
}

public enum ShapeEnum {
  circle, sun, square;
}
```

Then, in your code, you can do:

```
 try {
   Actions a = Actions.valueOf(command);
   Shapes s = Shapes.valueOf(shape);

   a.doCommand(myEnumMap.get(s));
 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
   // not a command, handle it
 }
```