# Function Calls from Main

Tags: java, function, program-entry-point

I have function A, function B, and function C

I am trying to call one of these function randomly (A or B or C) from Main.

How can i go about doing it?

Can i put the functions in an arraylist called FunctionList

Then do the following?

```
int x = (int)(Math.random() * Functionlist.size());
FunctionCall = FunctionList.get(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752192/array-of-function-pointers-in-java

Comment: Follow the answer in the comment above

Comment: What do you mean by function? Is it some method like `functionA()` or maybe some [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) class `FunctionA`?

Comment: I think he was hoping you could treat a funtion/method as an object, like you can do in other languages.

Comment: Another option would be to use reflection, though the comment above is likely a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of functions is small, the easiest way would be a `switch`,

```
switch((int)(Math.random()*NUM_FUNCTIONS) {
    case 0:
        functionA();
        break;
    case 1:
        functionB();
        break;
  //  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support function pointers. One workaround would be to name your functions methodically, i.e. f1, f2, f3, etc... and then create a Method object based off of that pattern. For example, using the function names f1, f2, f3, you could do this:

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
  methodName = "f" + String.valueOf((int) Math.random()*NUM_FUNCTIONS);
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ..); 
} catch (SecurityException e) {
  // ...
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  // ...
}
```

Then call the function like so:

```
try {
  method.invoke(obj, arg1, arg2,...);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
```

*This answer is heavily borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string).

Answer (score 0):

I'd mimic function objects the standard way by creating -maybe anonymous- classes implementing some interface `Function<T>` with a method `call(T arg)`, or even `Runnable`, if there's  no argument. Instances of those can be put into a collection