# How to dynamically call methods of Java Bean in for loop

Tags: java, android

How to dynamically call methods of Java Bean.

I have the following methods in a class of Java:

```
public class Bean {
   public String column1val;
   public String column2val;
   public String column2val;

}
```

I need to access these methods from for loop like the below:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) { 
    String s = Bean.get column+i+val;
}
```

How can we achieve this scenario ?

Comment: I think there is already answer for use of **Java Reflection** then no need to provide the same.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Bean {
    public String getMethod1(String a) {
        return a;
    }

    public String getMethod2(String a) {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
            NoSuchMethodException, IllegalArgumentException,
            IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
        Bean bean = new Bean();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            Method method = Bean.class.getMethod("getMethod" + i, String.class);
            System.out.println(method.invoke(bean, "Simple"));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use  **Java Reflections** for this purpose...

```
   //Obtain the Class instance
    Class beanClass = Bean.class;

    //Get the methods
    Method[] methods = beanClass.getMethods();

    //Loop through the methods and print out their names
    for (Method method : methods) {
        System.out.println(method.getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** as Java needs the **pre-qualified method names** to executes. Its not a String so you can append it.

This question helps you for your better understanding [Array of function pointers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752192/array-of-function-pointers-in-java)

Or **You can use Java Reflection as Other Suggest**..

Answer (score 1):

try as:

```
Bean beanobj=new Bean();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) { 

   Method method= beanobj.getClass().getMethod("getMethod"+
                                   String.valueOf(i), new Class[]{});
    String s=(String)method.invoke(beanobj,"aaa");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have use Reflection:

```
              MyBean m = new MyBean();
          Method[] methods =  m.getClass().getMethods();
          for(Method methid: methods){
              methid.invoke(m, "abc");
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```java
Bean b = new Bean();
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) { 
    String s = (String) Bean.getClass().getMethod("getMethod" + i, String.class).invoke(b, "aaa");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the list of methods and call them in a loop, if that's what is your requirement. As rightly said above you can not dynamically form the method names at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection it can be possible - But it is not really good way to call method -

```
Class<Bean> class1 =Bean.class;
for(int i=1;i<=2;i++) { 
    Method s = class1.getMethod("getMethod"+i, String.class);
    Object invoke = s.invoke(new Bean(),"Str");
    System.out.println(invoke);
}
```