# how to implement Java equivalent of Function Pointers via abstract classes

Tags: java, class, function, pointers, abstract

Im trying to to create a simple 4 function calculator using a jump table without switch case or if/else statements. I understand I can create the jump table via function pointers but I am kindda blanking out. I've started with the addition and subtraction part of the program but am trying to grasp the design/strategy to use. I am also getting an error when putting the method in the array, so far this is what i have:

```
public class Calculator {

          public abstract class Functor{

            abstract double Compute(double op1, double op2);
            }

     class Addition extends Functor
    {

        public double Compute(double op1, double op2){ return op1 + op2;}
    }

    class Subtraction extends Functor
    {

        public double Compute(double op1, double op2){ return op1 - op2;}
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Functor add = new Addition();     // Problem here
        Functor sub = new Subtraction();  // and here



    }
}
```

any help or ideas for the step in the right direction is greatly appreciated! 
thanks in advance!

Comment: every time this comes around, I really want to return to Scala!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the nearest substitute for a function pointer in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that's decent (aside from not having constructors that work right) I'd do it different, using anonymous classes.

```
abstract class Functor {


    public abstract double compute(double a, double b);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Functor add = new Functor() {
            // defining it here is essentially how you do a function pointer
            public double compute(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
        };

        Functor subtract = new Functor() {
            public double compute(double a, double b) { return a - b; }
        };

        System.out.println(add.compute(1.0,2.0));
        System.out.println(subtract.compute(1.0,2.0));

    }

}
```

Result:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Functor
3.0
-1.0

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this instead:

```
public enum Operation {
  PLUS("+") {
    double apply(double x, double y) { return x + y; }
  },
  MINUS("-") {
    double apply(double x, double y) { return x - y; }
  },
  TIMES("*") {
    double apply(double x, double y) { return x * y; }
  },
  DIVIDE("/") {
    double apply(double x, double y) { return x / y; }
  };
  private final String symbol;

  Operation(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol; 
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return symbol; 
  }
  abstract double apply(double x, double y);
}
```

This will only work if you're using Java 5 or later, which has generics and enums.  What this does is it gives you a static set of operations.  You access them by typing `Operation.PLUS` or `Operation.MINUS`, etc.

To test it try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
  double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);

  for (Operation op : Operation.values())
    System.out.printf("%f %s %f = %f%n", x, op, y, op.apply(x, y));
}
```

For more information consult *Effective Java, Second Edition* by Joshua Bloch.

It's worth pointing out that Java has no notion of "function pointers".  Rather you simple write an interface and write a class that implements that interface.  The correct class to use is selected at runtime; hence, that is a "jump table" but it's hidden behind the semantics of object-oriented programming.  This is known as **polymorphism**.

Comment: While reading about java design patterns there should also be a way to do this using an abstract class with 4 interfaces (one for each operation). I believe this is called the strategy pattern....Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any constructors to pass in any arguments to your sub-classes, I don't understand how you think `opt1` and `opt2` are going to be set without any constructors with those as parameters. This is not correct Java code right now.

Comment: It is Java code. It appears all his classes do start with Capitals, and while he may have a bug (he never gets to his variables) it is most certainly Java code.

Comment: they don't take any arguments

Comment: oops, silly me...edit has been made, now going to go figure out the problem with initializing the concrete classes.