# how to create pointer to function in j2me?

Tags: pointers, java-me, function-pointers

hello
how to create pointer to function in j2me?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function pointers in java. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java) topic can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry friend. There is no pointer concept in J2ME & java. Pointers are basically in C & C++.

The Java GarbageCollector manages all this task, so no need to have pointers.

Comment: Given the age of this thread it is best not to reopen it. Not unless the response adds something significantly different than previous responses.