# changing two values at a time in java

Tags: java, b-tree

How can I change two values concurrently. I am writing a code for b-tree in java. But i am unable to modify two variables at a time. Like in C , we do so by using pointers. But how to do so in java? I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: `Like in C , we do so by using pointers`: how? do you mean if you update a pointer value, all other ponters pointing to same address are also updated?

Comment: The JVM will only process one instruction at a time. You can't modify two variables concurrently. Unless you're talking about using threads?

Comment: Some sample (pseudo-)code and/or a more specific example would be useful.

Comment: ya we can modify two or more variables using pointers. In b-tree, one node breaks up to form two. Its easy to implement this function in c, but in java, lack of pointers makes it a tough question. Hope the people familiar with b-tree can understand my problem

Comment: All non-primitive variables in Java are references (another name for a pointer) to an object. It should work the same way as with pointers in C. Without seeing any code, it's hard to guess what you mean.

Comment: Or I can ask the same question in different wordings. How can I achieve those features in java which i can get in c using pointers? but this will be broad question to cover up here

Comment: @Partha: do you read the comments? Java variables which reference objects **are** pointers. Show us your code.

Comment: +1 to JB Nizet.  Pointers and references are two ways to say the same thing: a reference to an object/value in memory.

Comment: -2 to all of you. If you can use references everywhere then what is the use of pointers. Think before answering

Comment: what ever we can do by pointers can be done by references but it needs more line of code i feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but setting an object reference in Java is atomic. You can use that to change a set of multiple values at a time, e.g.:

```
class BTreeState {
    int foo;
    long bar;
    String whatever;
}

//here you change foo, bar, whatever all at once
state = new State(1, 2L, "something");
```

Answer (score 1):

If one of them is an integer you could use an `AtomicStampedReference`. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicStampedReference.html) for a definition.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=code%20for%20b-tree%20in%20java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) will help you writing b-tree code.

[nearest substitute for a function pointer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java)

You can also use cloning.