# Java - Run method passed through parameters?

Tags: java, methods, execute, void

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the nearest substitute for a function pointer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122407/whats-the-nearest-substitute-for-a-function-pointer-in-java)

How would you run a method that was passed through parameters?

Example:

```
public static void runThing(Void method) {
method();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection APIs in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As of Java 1.7, closures are not supported in the language.