# Java Closures - Current State

Tags: java, closures, java-7

There have been many threads that correspond to this topic.

[What’s the current state of closures in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116865/whats-the-current-state-of-closures-in-java)
[Closures in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233579/closures-in-java-7)

All of the inputs have been that java 7 is NOT getting closures.

It seems however closures will now be in java 7:

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/editor/archive/2009/12/03/mark-reinhold-answers-questions-closures-java-7

Does anyone have any other information or insight to this possibility?  Can anyone furthermore confirm or deny the state of closures?

Comment: While the answer has changed, the question is still an exact duplicate.

Comment: It is a duplicate, I posted a question in an original but someone suggested for me to create a new question, so I did:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116865/whats-the-current-state-of-closures-in-java/533063#533063

Comment: IMO if the answer has changed since the last time a question was asked, then asking a duplicate question should not come under criticism. I am glad this question was asked because it brought to my attention that Closures in Java are closer than I previously thought!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Artima](http://www.artima.com) has a [good summary](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=276&thread=274496) of the current (Dec 2009) situation.

> One year ago, Mark Reinhold, Principal
>   Engineer at Sun Microsystems,
>   announced At the Devoxx conference in
>   Antwerp, Belgium that the next major
>   release of Java, JDK 7, would not
>   include closures. At the same
>   conference this year, however,
>   Reinhold announced in a surprise turn
>   around the Java would be getting
>   closures after all in JDK 7

Answer (score 1):

Thats from [infoq](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/11/jdk7-simple-closures) about it (Dec 19).

Closures will be on JAVA 7 and the JDK 7 schedule will be extended until around September 2010