# Exception handling when composing functions on a Java 8 stream

Tags: java, exception, stream

With Java 8 and streams I do not really get how the exception handling should work when composing several functions?

I would like to write the following:

```
Arrays.stream((File[]) files).flatMap(file -> Files.lines(file.toPath()));
```

The compiler says there is an unhandled IOException at "`Files.lines(...)`"

Putting try catch around this statement does not work and declaring a throws not as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch IOException thrown from Files.lines inside a lambda.

[Java 8: Lambda-Streams, Filter by Method with Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757300/java-8-lambda-streams-filter-by-method-with-exception)

Comment: Is there any way to use an "inline" try catch expression as mentioned in this other thread? Or do I need to invent a separate uncheck method, which I would not consider very beautiful?