# ClassNotFoundException is magically unchecked

Tags: java, exception

My main worker thread looks like this:

```
public final class Worker
implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            _run();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // Cleanup carefully
        }
    }

    private void _run() {
        // do work here
    }
}
```

Imagine my surprise when `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` reported an uncaught instance of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, a checked exception.

(The root cause is a different issue: We were overwriting a JAR file in a dev environment during runtime.)

In my book, this looks like a [Sneaky Throw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19757456/257299).  Why is this exception not a RuntimeException?

Sample stacktrace (sanitised):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xyz
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:61)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:717)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:441)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:375)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:409)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:376)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:199)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:780)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:422)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why is this exception not a RuntimeException?*

This is the **Hierarchy** of `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

```
java.lang.Object
 java.lang.Throwable
  java.lang.Exception
   java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

As you see it does not extend in any way the `RuntimeException`, that has this Hierarchy

```
java.lang.Object
 java.lang.Throwable
  java.lang.Exception
   java.lang.RuntimeException
```

If you like to catch both of them; `catch Exception`,

if you like to catch all; `catch Throwable`

and `finally`, if you like to learn more about **hierarchy** and **inheritance** you can start here: [Inheritance - Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, ClassNotFoundException is not a RuntimeException but your code dont need to catch it because is the Virtual machine the one that try to load all the needed classes.

If your code try to load a class through class loader you must catch the ClassNotFound, like this

```
package a;

public class B {

    public void testLoadClass() {

        try {
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("java.util.ArrayList");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I think the fact to be a Checked exception is ok in order to be aware of non existing classes in compilation time. In this way you can control the flow code. If that exception is not a checked exception, you would lost the code control in compilation time. It´s only an opinion

Answer (score 0):

`RuntimeException`s are unexpected exceptions really. (e.g. a `NullPointerException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException`), usually caused by bugs. It only makes sense that you don't need to write code to cover for potential bugs.

**In contrast a checked exception (e.g. `FileNotFoundException`) is more likely to happen**. And therefore you either need to cover (catch) it, or you need to make clear that you didn't cover it (by adding a `throws` clause) .

So, the real question is, is a `ClassCastException` (or any other `ReflectiveOperationExeption`) something that you should cover.

**I think it is arguable.** There has been some discussion about the use of checked exceptions in the last years. So opinions differ at the moment.