# Java 8 - stream - method in filter has unhandled exception, try catch is expecting return statement

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-stream

I am using a function call is filter on a stream like below -

```
list.stream()
        .filter(a -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(a.getProp1()))
        .filter(a -> !a.getProp1().matches(“(.*)xyz"))
        .filter(a -> {try {
                        return isValid(a.getProp1());
                    } catch (javax.naming.NamingException e) {
                        logger.error("Error");
                    }
                    })
```

I referred to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757300/java-8-lambda-streams-filter-by-method-with-exception) But I don't want to throw an exception in the catch block. I just want to log it.

I want to retain the records which return true on invoking isValid(a) and then be able to collect it in a HashSet like below --

```
 //   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

It must be obvious from code but I am new to java 8 and still learning concepts. Please pardon any naive code. Thanks for any help.

Comment: in the 3rd filter, when you catch your exception, should be the "a" filtered out or not? Not missing a "return false" or sth like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are filtering, if the `isValid` method throws a `javax.naming.NamingException`, apart from logging the exception, you might want to return `false`:

```
Set<Whatever> result = list.stream()
    .filter(a -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(a.getProp1()))
    .filter(a -> !a.getProp1().matches("(.*)xyz"))
    .filter(a -> {
        try {
            return isValid(a.getProp1());
        } catch (javax.naming.NamingException e) {
            logger.error("Error");
            return false;
        }})
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

This is because the `Predicate` argument passed to the `Stream.filter` method must always return a boolean value, no matter if it has catched an exception or not.

Comment: That makes sense, even after adding a `return false`, I am not able to collect the list which is an arraylist into a hashSet. I get a compilation error saying 'Bad return type in method reference.

Comment: `Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet = list.stream()
        .filter(a -> !StringUtils.isEmpty(a.getProp1()))
        .filter(a -> !a.getProp1().matches(“(.*xyz”))
        .filter(a -> {try {
                        return isValid(a.getProp1());
                    } catch (javax.naming.NamingException e) {
                        logger.error("Error");
                        return false;
                    }
                    })
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));` This is my final code.

Comment: @maddie Please check if it works after my last edit. The other strange thing I notice is the use of typographic quotes in the second `filter(...)`...

Comment: @maddie The other problem is the `Set<String> mySet`. Is it really a set of strings? I think it's a set of some object of yours, while `getProp1()` returns an actual string.

Comment: Yes, you guessed it right, I will fix it. I guess I will reassign the modified list to list itself in that case. Thanks so much.

Comment: @maddie So you only want to remove elements from the original list?

Comment: I actually added a `.map(a -> a.getProp1())` after all the filters. i am able to collect it as a HashSet<String>. Thanks!

Comment: @maddie OK, that makes sense. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149639/discussion-between-federico-peralta-schaffner-and-maddie).