# Why doesn't Lambda understand throws in method signature?

Tags: java, exception, lambda

In the following code, I wrote throws in the method signature, but again in Lambda for **write**, the compiler gives an error. Why?

compiler error: Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException

```
 public void saveTodoItems() throws IOException {

    try (BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("TodoItems.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {

        todoItems.forEach(todoItem -> {
                outputStream.write(todoItem.getShortDescription() + "\t" //compile error on write
                        + todoItem.getDetail() + "\t"
                        + todoItem.getDeadLine()+"\n");

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `todoItems`? Some kind of list? And what's the error?

Comment: @byxor yes it is an array list and the compiler error is: Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException

Comment: `IOException` is a "checked exception". Whatever interface you've implemented with your lambda, it doesn't declare that the method will throw an IOException. You probably need a try/catch inside your lambda

Comment: @byxor "*Whatever interface you've implemented*" it's forEach of Iterable, so it's just java.util.function.Consumer.

Comment: Just use a regular for-loop here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that lambdas are supposed to be implementations of functional interfaces. In this case, [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) takes the functional interface [`Consumer<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html) as a parameter.

```
void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)
```

So your lambda is actually implementing the single abstract method in the `Consumer` interface - [`accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept(T)). This method is not declared to throw any exceptions:

```
void accept(T t); // no throws clause here at all!
```

Therefore, the `IOException` that the `write` call could throw is considered to be unhandled. The fact that you have added a `throws` clause to your `saveTodoItems` method is irrelevant.

On the other hand, if you have declared your own functional interface that does have a `throws` clause in its single abstract method:

```
interface IOConsumer<T> {
    void accept(T t) throws IOException;
}
```

It is possible to write:

```
IOConsumer<TodoItem> consumer = todoItem -> {
    outputStream.write(todoItem.getShortDescription() + "\t"
                    + todoItem.getDetail() + "\t"
                    + todoItem.getDeadLine()+"\n");
};
```

Of course, you would not be able to use this in `forEach`, because it only accepts a `Consumer`, not an `IOConsumer`. You should surround the `write` with a try...catch, or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757300/java-8-lambda-streams-filter-by-method-with-exception) for more alternatives.