# How to filter nested loops using Java 8 streams and filters?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two simple POJOs:

```
public class Parent {
    String name;
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
    void addChild(Integer age) { children.add(new Child(age)); }
}

public class Child {
    Integer age;
}
```

Then I generate some data, I add for parent 100 children:

```
List<Parent> parentList = new ArrayList<>();

Parent first = new Parent("first");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { first.addChild(i); }
parentList.add(first);
```

My goal is to remove all children younger than ten:

```
parentList.stream().forEach(parent -> {
    parent.setChildren(getChildrenOlderThan(parent));
});

List<Child> getChildrenOlderThan10(Parent parent) {
    return parent.getChildren().stream()
        .filter(child -> child.getAge() > 10)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Finally I have list children older than ten. But I do not want to write a separate method getChildrenOlderThan.

How to get all parents with list chilrden older than ten using only the single stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nice method [`Collection.removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method.

For example:

```
class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Parent> parentList = new ArrayList<>();

        // init parents with children

        parentList.forEach(parent -> 
             parent.getChildren().removeIf(Example::childOlderThan10)
        );

    }

    static boolean childOlderThan10(Child child) {
        return child != null && child.getAge() > 10;
    }
}
```

See more: [Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), [`Collection.stream().forEach()` vs `Collection.forEach()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218874/what-is-difference-between-collection-stream-foreach-and-collection-foreach)

Comment: Make sure `parent.getChildren()` returns a copy of the list in parent or the list of children inside your parent object will have changed.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe If `parent.getChildren()` returns a copy than this cope won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You may inline the method getChildreanOlderThan like this:

```
parentList.stream().forEach(parent -> {
    parent.setChilds(parent.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(child -> child.getAge() > 10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    });
```

Comment: Sure, it will work. But some suggestions: `stream()` on `parentList` is useless here, This kind of filtering is harder to read and maintain.

Comment: @Andrii I as well like your solution more than mine. But could you explain why the `stream()` on `parentList` is useless? Does it not fulfill the goal? Do I have a bug in the implementation?

Comment: See please: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218874/what-is-difference-between-collection-stream-foreach-and-collection-foreach

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of child > 10 using Flatmap

```
List < Child > childList = parentList.stream().flatMap(par - > par.getChildren().stream())
    .filter(child - > child.age > 10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```