# Performance difference between Stream.map and Collectors.mapping

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, collectors

Last time I was discovering nooks of the functional programming of Java 8 and above and I found out a static method `mapping` in Collectors class.

We have a class Employee like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  private Double salary;
}
```

Let's say that we have a POJO list of `Employee` class and we want to receive a list of all names of Employees. We have two approaches likes:

````
    List<Employee> employeeList
        = Arrays.asList(new Employee("Tom Jones", 45, 15000.00),
        new Employee("Harry Andrews", 45, 7000.00),
        new Employee("Ethan Hardy", 65, 8000.00),
        new Employee("Nancy Smith", 22, 10000.00),
        new Employee("Deborah Sprightly", 29, 9000.00));

    //IntelliJ suggest replacing the first approach with ```map``` and ```collect```

    List<String> collect =
        employeeList
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.mapping(Employee::getName, Collectors.toList()));

    List<String> collect1 =
        employeeList
            .stream()
            .map(Employee::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
````

I know that the first approach uses a terminal operation on `Stream` and the second one intermediate operation on `Stream` but I want to know if the first approach will have worse performance than second and vice-versa. I would be grateful if you could explain the potential performance degradation for the first case when our data source (employeeList) will significantly increase in size.

EDIT:

I created a simple two test cases which were supplied by records generated in a simple for loop. Accordingly for small data input the difference between ,,traditional'' approach with `Stream.map` usage and `Collectors.mapping` is marginal. On the other hand in a scenario when we are intensively increasing the number of data like `30000000` surprisingly Collectors.mapping starts working a little bit better. So as not to be empty-handed for data input `30000000` Collectors.mapping lasts `56 seconds` for 10 iterations as `@RepeatedTest` and with the same data input for the same iteration more recognizable approach like `Stream.map` and then `collect` last `5 second longer`. I know that my provisional tests are not the best and it cannot illustrate reality due to JVM optimization but we can claim that for huge data input `Collectors.mapping` can be more desirable. Anyway, I think that this

Comment: Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334705/ways-to-map-the-list-of-objects-to-another-list-of-objects/58334853#58334853), its a similar question. Lots of varieties, empirical data and a link to further posts of the same kind. With the resulting baseline argument, that there are differences, but they don't matter.

Comment: @Naman I have seen this post but this question answered a question why we need ```mapping``` and similar methods which are simplifying collect operation on our stream.

Comment: I'll quote from Andy's answer *I doubt there is a meaningful performance difference. **You'd have to benchmark it on your data to know for sure.***

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a meaningful performance difference. You'd have to benchmark it on your data to know for sure.

Note that `mapping` isn't actually intended to be used directly as a collector, but rather as a downstream collector within another collector:

> The `mapping()` collectors are most useful when used in a multi-level reduction, such as downstream of a groupingBy or partitioningBy.

There is something in *Effective Java* 3rd Edition about this too (in Item 46, about 2/3 of the way down page 214, the paragraph starting "The collectors returned by the `counting` method"). Basically, it says not to use things like `mapping` in the first way you do here.