# Cannot return List<T> using builder in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, build

I have a save method that returns `CommandDTO`.

```
// ...

final MenuItem saved = menuItemRepository.save(menuItem);
return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(saved.getUuid()).build();
```

Here is my `CommandDTO`:

```
@Value
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CommandDTO {
    UUID uuid;
}
```

On the other hand, I change the method to accept list of request instead of single request and it should return list of saved record as `List<CommandDTO>`. However, I cannot create necessary return clause:

```
final List<MenuItem> saved = menuItemRepository.saveAll(menuItems);

// here I have the uuid list of the saved records
List<UUID> uuidList = saved.stream().map(MenuItem::getUuid)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

return List<CommandDTO>().builder().uuid(uuidList).build(); // ???
```

How should I return value as `List<CommandDTO>`?

Comment: You're calling `builder()` on the `List` interface, not on the actual class. Using fluid API for such a simple class seems a bit redundant. Anyway, what you probably want to do is convert every `UUID` in your list into an instance of your class, perhaps by using `map()` just like you do a couple of lines before your return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `map` on the stream of `UUID`s to convert them.

```
return saved.stream().map(MenuItem::getUuid)
    .map(uuid -> CommandDTO.builder().uuid(uuid).build())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. I have some questions regarding to `map()` and `stream()`.

Comment: **1.** We can also perform this via `foreach` I think. What is the difference?

Comment: **2.** In some cases, we can omit `stream()` especially I use `foreach`. What is the difference when using `stream()` or not using `stream()` in that cases?

Comment: @Henry `forEach` is used for looping over a stream/collection, while `map` is used to convert each element. `forEach` can be directly called on a collection or a stream. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218874/what-is-difference-between-collection-stream-foreach-and-collection-foreach

Comment: What about 2nd question?

Comment: @Henry Check the link I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218874/what-is-difference-between-collection-stream-foreach-and-collection-foreach

Comment: In this case, should we generally prefer using `stream()` or not?

Comment: @Henry No problem. In this case, `stream` is appropriate since you are calling `map`.

Comment: What if I use `forEach`? It is possible to use `stream()`or not. Should I prefer  `stream()` when using `forEach`? Or should not?

Comment: If you use forEach for this particular problem, you'll need to add items to a new `List`, which is more cumbersome than `stream` and `map`.

Comment: I asked in general situation. Assume that to I use `forEach` or `map` and it is possible to use or not `stream()`. In this scene, should I use `stream()` ?

Comment: It's up to you to decide which one to use, depending on efficiency and conciseness. There is no rule for this.

Comment: Ok, I know. But as I have no experience, I just want to get your valuable suggestion under your experience.

Comment: It really depends on each case. Generally, use the method that is more expressive for what you want to do. For example, `stream` and `map` should be used when you want to transform the elements in a collection. `forEach` is used for general iteration.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your good explanations and helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a List to a method that accepts a single UUID. You can add a map to your stream chain

```
List<CommandDTO> resultList = saved.stream()
.map(MenuItem::getUuid)
.map(uuid -> CommandDTO.builder(uuid).build())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are a few different ways to accomplish this. This isn't necessarily the most efficient though. Hopefully it answered your question.