# Iterating over a hashmap of arraylist

Tags: java

```
Set set = hm.entrySet();
Iterator i = set.iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();

    // me.getValue should point to an arraylist
    Iterator<Student> it = (me.getValue()).iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) { 
        // some code
    }
}
```

Ok, I tried iterating over an Arraylist and for some reason it doesn't work, the compiler tells me that it cannot find the symbol. I know that me.getValue() should point to an object and in this case the value part of the key/value pair is an Arraylist. So, what's wrong?

Comment: Post stacktrace please

Comment: You mean the build output?

Comment: [What is stacktrace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors), but it is generated at runtime, while your problem seems to be compilation time one.

Comment: symbol:   method iterator()
  location: class Object
1 error

Comment: There was no exception thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
 Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
```

you're creating an untyped instance of Map.Entry, which is like doing

```
 Map.Entry<Object, Object> me = ...
```

Then, when you try to do

```
Iterator<Student> it = (me.getValue()).iterator();
```

this is the equivalent of trying to do

```
ArrayList<Object> objects;
Strudent s = objects.get(0);
```

which, obviously, you cannot do. Instead, you need to instantiate your Map.Entry object with the appropriate type:

```
 Map.Entry<YourKeyType, ArrayList<Student>> me =  
       (Map.Entry<YourKeyType, ArrayList<Student>>) i.next();
```

Note that you can avoid the cast there, and take full advantage of [generic type safety](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), by making your iterator an `Iterator<YourKeyType, ArrayList<Student>>` rather than declaring it as a raw type.

Comment: Is this something I could have found out just by reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes it is, but generics are a fairly large concept to wrap your head around, I recommend you start by looking at the tutorial I linked to.

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that this is the "older-style" iteration which doesn't tend to be used as much anymore vs. the newer *for-each* iteration (or even newer `Iterable.forEach` in Java 8) [More Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-f).