# Java 8 way to repeat a block of code x times

Tags: java, java-8

Maybe a normal for loop is still the right way but I wanted to see if there is a more succinct way to do it in java 8.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++) {
     // Code
 }
```

Is there a more java 8 way to do this.  I don't actually need i just need to repeat something x number of times.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: `IntStream.range().forEach()` will do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532488/does-java-8-provide-a-good-way-to-repeat-a-value-or-function?rq=1 maybe this?

Comment: See also [“How to create nice iterations in Java 8”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27779568/2711488)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way I can see on how to do this would be something like `IntStream.range(0, LIMIT).forEach($ -> code)`.

Comment: Could you clarify why you use dollar sign for the identifier? Is it a convention to use `$` when it's unused. Also, could this ever cause a conflict (for the same reason `$` usage in identifiers is cautioned)

Comment: @swalog In other languages `_` is used to signify unused parameters, but that isn't allowed in Java, so just pick what you want. I'm not the only one using it (see Peter's answer), but I doubt there's any wide spread idiom. The compiler uses `$` for inner classes (no risk there), a few special fields like `$assertionsDisabled ` and presumably (not checked) methods created from lambdas (again no risk there). Pick whatever you want.

Comment: You will to do a lot if the 'code' called in the Lambda function throws checked exception. You cannot throw a checked exception in Java8 Lambda.

Answer (score 10):

One of the reasons to use IntStream is to add parallel-ism, assuming you understand the impact of this.

```
IntStream.range(0, LIMIT).parallel().forEach($ -> {
    // some thing thread safe.
});
```