# How to access Outer Variable of for loop in java8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Following is My Code

```
List<Lead> Mylead = adminService.GetMyData(10);
int i=0;
Mylead.forEach(lead->{
  i++;
});
```

> Error : Local variable I defined in an enclosing scope must be final
>   or effectively final

Comment: make it `final`, but what's the detailed use case?

Comment: why you want to change value inside the for loop , and with a constant literal? add some more details in your question

Comment: Related questions: [Java 8 Lambda variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40862845/8097737) and [why variables inside foreach loop of java8 should be final?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31801313/8097737)

Comment: The language has been designed to make stupid things harder. Just write `int i = Mylead.size();` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a wrapper for `i`, a simple way to do this would be an array.

```
List<Lead> Mylead = adminService.GetMyData(10);
final int[] i={0};
Mylead.forEach(lead->{
  i[0]++;
});
```

---

For a detailed explanation how this works see: [Java 8 Lambda variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40862997/8097737)

Comment: I want to increment variable i Here is my code : List<Lead> Mylead = adminService.GetMyData(10);
    int i=0;
  Mylead.forEach(lead->{
   i++;
  });

Comment: Thanks.It's Work for me.But What is the problem With My Code.Any Reason?Why should Variable "i" is not accessed?

Comment: @RahulParmar Because lambdas and state don't mix well. Use a normal for loop instead.