# Java8 filter and change properties simultaneously

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Reading through [this article](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/), I can filter the collection like this:

```
Set<Status> statusClone = cloner.deepClone(statusList).stream().filter(s -> !(s instanceof FileMetadata)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

However, I will also need to set the properties simultaneously filtering them. 
After filtering them, I currently iterate through each one and then set properties:

```
for (Iterator<Status> iterator = statusClone.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        {
            Status s = iterator.next();
//          if (s instanceof FileMetadata)
//          {
//              iterator.remove();
//              continue;
//          }
            s.setStatus(JobStatus.UNINITIATED);
            s.setLastAccessedTime(0);
            s.setOffSet(null);
            s.setStreamNo(null);
        }
        statusList.addAll(statusClone);
```

Is this possible in Java8 without using foreach?

EDIT:
From the comments, I agree that I can clone inside the filter. Thanks.

Comment: Problem is that your code isn't very functional (you do not have an immutable Status for one) so it's awkward to write it using Stream.

Comment: If you are going to set the same values again and again for different objects, put that in a new method and call the method from the stream.

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to know to use without foreach on the collection. I'm iterating through the collect again. If this is the case, then I could avoid lambdas and use a conventional for loop using an iterator.

Comment: You are on the right track when you say that you could avoid using lambas  and use a conventional for loop, however, you don’t need to deal with an `Iterator`. Use `for(Status s: statusClone) { /* manipulate s */ }`. You can use this since Java 5…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `peek`:

```
private static void initStatus(Status s) {
  s.setStatus(JobStatus.UNINITIATED);
  s.setLastAccessedTime(0);
  s.setOffSet(null);
  s.setStreamNo(null);
}

Set<Status> statusClone = cloner.deepClone(statusList).stream()
                  .filter(s -> !(s instanceof FileMetadata))
                  .peek(MyClass::initStatus)
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) warning that it could create issues if you use a parallel stream because you are modifying state.

---

It would be better to initialise the status directly when cloning the original list - something like:

```
private static Status cloneAndInitStatus(Status s) {
  Status clone = new Status(s);
  clone.setStatus(JobStatus.UNINITIATED);
  clone.setLastAccessedTime(0);
  clone.setOffSet(null);
  clone.setStreamNo(null);
  return clone;
}

Set<Status> statusClone = statusList.stream()
                  .filter(s -> !(s instanceof FileMetadata))
                  .map(MyClass::cloneAndInitStatus)
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That way you avoid state modifications during the stream.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
Set<Status> statusClone = cloner.deepClone(statusList)
                            .stream() 
                            .filter(s -> !(s instanceof FileMetadata))
                            .peek(s -> {
                                s.setStatus(JobStatus.UNINITIATED);
                                s.setLastAccessedTime(0);
                                s.setOffSet(null);
                                s.setStreamNo(null);
                            })
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

But it's a bit awkward since we're directly mutating an Object inside the `peek` method.

It would be better to write a copy constructor of `Status` and then use `map` instead of `peek` to map each status to a new status with this constructor.