# How do I access the first non null term of a List in Java?

Tags: java, list, oop, null, java-8

So I have a method (of which I can't change the parameters, or else this could have been made easier through HashMaps...more on this later), that passes an item as a parameter. Now I have a list of instances from this other class, of which one of its attributes is of the same type of this item, and I want to find the instances in the list which correspond to this item (of which there should be only one). This is what I did to find this:

```
List<Instance> instances = ...

public static void checkItems(Item i) {

    List<Instance> n = new ArrayList<>();
    instances.forEach(p -> n.add(p.i == i ? p : null));

    Instance currentInstance = n.get(0); 
    //Instance currentInstance = instances.stream().filter(p -> p.i == i).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);

}
```

You'll probably notice two things straight up:

1. I used a conditional operator which adds a null value to the list when the condition isn't passed
2. My commented code which was another attempt to solve this issue

So in the first case, I put null because it requires you to put something, and a null value is probably easier to work with, which is why the question arises: How do I access the first non-null value in a list (without resorting to iterating over the entire list to find it...)?

You may notice that I just assign the first value of the list with `n.get(0)` to `currentInstance`, because I know that only one value will have passed the test. However, due to some other code that I apply to `currentInstance`, this value cannot be null.

Just a note on the second point: the way I tried to solve it with streams actually works exactly as planned, except that for some reason the list of instances recovered is not a direct copy of the original instances. This resulted in the values of some of the attributed to have been reset to default values, therefore rendering this method useless.

EDIT: I just wanted to mention that the streams method wasn't working because of some silly mistake that I made in another class, there was nothing wrong with the code so I'll be using that bit to solve my problem :D

Comment: `instances.forEach(p -> if (p.i == i) n.add(p));`

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what your question is, and what this method is supposed to do. It doesn't return anything, and doesn't modify any state, so it does nothing.

Comment: @JBNizet That's because it's just a snippet of this kinda big thing I'm writing, I didn't want any added confusion by writing all the other pointless code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that only one `p` passes the test, I don't know what the point of creating a list with a load of `null` values plus `p` is.

Your problem seems to stem from wanting to use `forEach`. In my opinion, you should [almost always use a for loop in preference to forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20177092/3973077). With a simple `for` loop you can just use `break` when the item is found.

In detail:

```
Instance p = null;
for (Instance q : instances) {
    if (q.i == i) {
        p = q;
        break;
    }
}
if (p == null)
    throw new IllegalStateException();   // It wasn't there.
// Do something with p.
```

Comment: Yeah, `forEach()` is for when you want to do something with every element. It's not a drop-in substitute for a loop.

Comment: That's why my first approach was to use streams, but then I was getting that weird problem with the attributes (probably related to some other problem actually).

Comment: @Radiodef I never use it. I really like the answer I linked to even though it's more of a rant.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I never would have thought about using it either, except a classmate of mine reminded me that our teacher presented it to us in class, prompting us to use it when we could. This is probably only because we haven't actually officially seen streams in class yet, so it's just a placeholder for now

Comment: `forEach()` is really more like a toy. It's just convenient syntax for some extremely simple loops.

Comment: @Radiodef I'll keep that in mind going forward :D, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

```
Instance currentInstance = instances.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.i == i)
    .findFirst()
    .get(); // you can use get if you are sure there's one instance
```

The predicate `p -> p.i == i` seems suspicious. Why not using `equals()` instead?

Answer (score 3):

As described, this would normally be solved with streams in the following way:

```
Optional<Instance> first =
    instances.stream().filter(p -> p.i == i).findFirst();
```

> (of which there should be only one)

Of which there *definitely* is only one, or of which there *might be* more than one. (And if there's more than one, then what? Is that an error?) It sounds like it might be that you should have a `Set<Instance>`, not a `List<Instance>`. Just an observation.

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated than that in the actual program, I just wanted to keep a little bit of context which is why I mentioned these restrictions. All in all I was just interested on how to solve this specific problem

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like

```
instances.forEach(p -> {
   if (p.i == i) n.add(p);
});
```

Comment: Ok great, I didn't know you could use this kind of syntax, thanks!

Comment: Eclipse tells me the correct syntax is `...(p -> {if (p.i  == i) n.add(p);});` with the added `;` before the `}`. I hope this is right...