# Using Lambda Expression for switching windows in Selenium Using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, lambda, java-8

```
for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
{
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 
}
```

Can we rewrite this using Lambda Expression?

Comment: Is it really required to execute `driver.switchTo()` again in every loop iteration? If not, you can simply use `driver.getWindowHandles().forEach(driver.switchTo()::window)`

Answer (score 2):

I would go for

```
driver.getWindowHandles().forEach(windowHandle -> {
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
});
```

which is equivalent to:

```
for(String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}
```

`forEach` method calls can be used for `Collections`.
You can go parallel with the usage of `forEach` together with `parallelStream`. [Read further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop).

Comment: Some explanation might help.

Comment: @Pavlo, added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
driver.getWindowHandles().stream().forEach((i) -> {
     driver.switchTo().window(i);
});
```

or like

```
driver.getWindowHandles().parallelStream().forEachOrdered((i) -> {
     driver.switchTo().window(i);
});
```

Stream api offers other possibilities that can make your life easier.