# Return a value from Java 8 forEach loop

Tags: java, java-8

In the below example , someObjects is a set. I am trying to return true if a condition matches within the loop , however this doesn't seem to compile. However when I just add "return" it works fine.What is the issue that I need to fix?

```
public boolean find(){

    someObjects.forEach(obj -> {
       if (some_condition_met) {
          return true;
       }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Compilation Errors

> The method forEach(Consumer) in the type
>   Iterable is   not applicable for the arguments ((
>   obj) -> {})

Comment: Where do you add "return" to make it work?

Comment: What are the compiler errors? Add the output to the question.

Comment: It is impossible to return from the outer method inside the body of a lambda. Use a for loop instead

Comment: Thanks @cppbeginner. So when I add a return (without return value) , it just exits the loop?

Comment: @AntonH I added return instead of return true.

Comment: The method being implemented by the lambda is `public void accept(Object t)`, the `return` type is `void` so `return;` is valid but `return true;` is not.

Comment: Return inside the lambda passed to forEach is like continue in a normal loop.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use `forEach`?  Really, the best solution for this is the old-fashioned one.  You don't need the Java 8 goodies here.

Comment: I love this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20177092/6253321

Comment: Thanks @DawoodibnKareem. Appreciate your help , will switch to old fashioned for-loop. I didn't have any specific reason for using it.

Comment: Might be simpler to just use `findFirst()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `forEach` method in a `Collection`  expects a `Consumer` which means a function that takes a value, but doesn't return anything. That's why you can't use `return true;` but a `return;` works fine.

I you want to break out of the loop when your condition is met, it's better to use a simple `for(...)` loop. I assumed that the type of `obj` is `Object`:

```
for (Object obj : someObjects) {
  if (some_condition_met) {
    return true;
  }
}

return false;
```

Comment: Thanks , how does return work when the return is void , I assume? Do return just exit the loop?

Comment: No. In your example a `return;` will simply exit the lambda and proceed to the next element in the collection. The loop will not be ended.

Comment: Thank you! So I guess it is same as continue.

Comment: Yes, it's effectively the same as a `continue` in a "standard" loop.

Answer (score 16):

I guess you want to do this:

```
public boolean find(){
    return someObjects.stream().anyMatch(o -> your_condition);
}
```

Comment: Probably not.  There's an overhead in building a stream.  Much better to do it the old-fashioned (pre Java 8) way.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem i assume OP wants something in functional style. judging from his scores, he should know how to do it in the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Maybe, but this is clearly a case where the "functional style" is the wrong solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do the old fashioned way then.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem how can you be so affirmative about it? This solution is perfectly fine. In fact, this is even clearly a case where the functional solution is cleaner and simpler than the old-style one. If it's about the overhead, how is that a problem? You should never use streams if you don't accept their overhead.

Comment: @DidierL I entirely agree with you. real life software practice puts micro performance like this to the very back of the priority queue. there are lots of arguments to object that claim.

Comment: OK, "wrong" was the wrong word for me to use.  How about "not as good"?  I would _never_ favour a solution that builds a stream over a solution that doesn't; and I certainly don't find this "cleaner and simpler" than the old-fashioned solution, once you write the lambda out in full.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Considering everything implemented with streams can be rewritten without, by your logic you should never use streams then.

Answer (score 4):

`forEach` accepts a `Consumer` therefore you cannot pass in a behaviour that does not return *void*. you need to do something like:

```
return someObjects.stream().anyMatch(e -> condition);
```