# convert java for loop into stream with filter

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have transformed a regular for loop code into java 8 streams. I tried a few, but  i am still learning this and running out of ideas, please suggest ideas. can this be further simplified ? Other than using forEach, I am not able to change much. 
Also, why do I have to typecast  the eid to String in getERecordFromId((String)eid)

```
Stream <String>eIdsStream = getEidStream();

final HashSet<String> declinedRecords = new HashSet<>();

eIdsStream.forEach (eid ->  {
        ERecord eRecord = getERecordFromId((String)eid);
        if(eRecord.getEHash() != null &&  Status.DECLINED == eRecord.getStatus()) {
            declineRecords.add(eRecord.getEHash());
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Replacing your for-each loops with Stream.forEach might not be a great idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635398/java-8-iterable-foreach-vs-foreach-loop).

Comment: Now that you changed your variable to a `Stream<String>`, you don't need the casting to `String`, so at least that part of your question is no longer relevant (perhaps you should edit it out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The casting is required since you use a raw `Stream` variable. Assuming `getEidStream()` returns a `Stream<String>`, you should have assigned it to a `Stream<String>` variable, or not assigned it to a variable at all.

Using `forEach` defeats the purpose of using `Stream`s in the first place.

You should use `filter` and `map` to transform the `Stream` to hold the required elements, and then collect to a `Set`.

```
Set<String> declinedRecords =
    getEidStream().map(eid -> getERecordFromId(eid))
                  .filter(eRecord -> eRecord.getEHash() != null &&  Status.DECLINED == eRecord.getStatus())
                  .map(ERecord::getEHash)
                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: And to answer your question about casting `eid`, it's because you have defined a `Stream` without specifying the generic parameter `Stream<String>`.

Comment: ok.. this makes sense. but I get compile error for eRecord.getEHash()  and eRecord.getStatus() --- cannot resolve method  and also ERecord::getEHash  -- cannot access non static method as static

Comment: @Roma what kind of method is `getEHash`? Is it an instance method of `ERecord` or a static method of that class? The `eRecord.getEHash()` call in your question suggests it's an instance method. You can always replace it with a lambda expression if the method reference doesn't work (`eRecord -> eRecord.getEHash()`)

Comment: it is an instance method of ERecord.

Comment: @Roma Does the code in your question pass compilation?

Comment: @Roma does `getEidStream()` return a `Stream<String>` or a raw `Stream`? Tat could be the problem.

Comment: @Eran, It does return a Stream<String>

Comment: @Roma did you try the exact code posted in my answer? Assuming that the code in your question passed compilation, the code in my answer should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193869/discussion-between-roma-and-eran).